# Objects are not valid as a React child - Unable to display value from object in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, momentjs

I have a `moment()` object in my React application which looks like this [image]-

This is stored in a state variable called `scheduleDate`.

When I try to display the value of `_d` from the moment object on the frontend by simply doing

`<p>{this.state.scheduleDate._d}</p>` it gives me this error -

*Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Fri Apr 30 2021 15:02:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

I've tried different ways but nothing works out. Any idea what's going wrong and how can I overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in `console` is likely the [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) representation of JavaScript's [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

Try the following instead:

```
<p>{this.state.scheduleDate._d.toString()}</p>
```

Comment: This works! How can I just display `28th April, 2021` from this string?

Comment: For that you prob need to use `format()` method of your moment object according to [these formatting rules](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/) It'll look something like `<p>{obj.format("Do MMMM, YYYY")}</p>`